# Invoke Javascript on ValidationSummary ShowSummary

Tags: asp.net, javascript, validation

I am trying to invoke a javascript function when a ValidationSummary shows the errors on a page.

Is this possible?

Comment: No...I had to work around it.

Comment: Are you going to post your workaround for others?

Comment: No... I basically redesigned the page so i dont have to use javascript. No use for the question at hand.

Answer (score 3):

if you do not find another way to make a "JS user function", you can try this way:

```
var oldValidationSummaryOnSubmit = ValidationSummaryOnSubmit;
var ValidationSummaryOnSubmit = function(validationGroup){

    /*
    my code before
    */

    // call old (MS ASP.NET function) ValidationSummaryOnSubmit
    oldValidationSummaryOnSubmit(validationGroup);

    /*
    my code  after
    */

}
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there isn't any event that fired after validation summary showed. But at client side we can check if the page is valid by **Page_IsValid** variable. Check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx) for more information.

Comment: this is what I was looking for, great!